# UITableView Delete Editing Style only available when admin is logged in

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, edit-tableview

How do I make the UItableView Delete Editing Style to be only available when the logged-in user is the admin? When another user is logged in or no user is logged in, the Delete option appears when the row is swiped to the left, although the delete action is only performed when the logged-in user is the admin, I don't want it to appear when the row is swiped left. Please help.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if MUser.currentUser() != nil {
            if MUser.currentUser()!.email == kADMIN {

                if editingStyle == .delete {

                    let voucherToDelete = voucherArray[indexPath.row]

                    voucherArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    tableView.reloadData()

                    print("This is the voucherToDelete \(voucherToDelete.id!)")

                    deleteVoucherFirestore(voucherToDelete.id!) { (error) in


                        if error != nil {
                            print("error udpating the voucher", error!.localizedDescription)
                        }
                        self.loadItems()
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement this func in your code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    guard let user = MUser.currentUser(), user.email == kADMIN else { return false }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I'll accept your answer in few minutes.